# How to do you compute the probability a record occurring in a sequence of independent experiments?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider a sequence of independent experiments, each of which produces a random integer in N with the probability mass function ${p_k}$.  The pmf is the same for all the experiments and also strictly positive, i.e. $p_k > 0$ for all k $\in N$. We say that a $record$ occurs in the $n$th experiment if its outcome is strictly greater than the outcome of all previous experiments (1st through (n-1)th) and we denote that event by $A_n$.

How do I show for $n>=2$

$P[A_n]= \sum_{k=2}^\infty p_k (\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}p_i)^{n-1}$

My understanding is I need to use theorem 4.3 on pg. 59 or theorem 4.4 on pg. 60 of [this book](http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/mathsandphysics/measure/billingsleyprobabilityandmeasure.pdf), however I'm not sure how to apply them.  I would appreciate all / any advice from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_n$ denote the outcome of the experiment at time $n$. Then

$$
\begin{split}
P(A_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X_{m}<k \;\forall k \;|\;X_n=k)P(X_n = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \prod_{m=1}^{n-1} P(X_m < k) \right) p_k \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i \right)^{n-1} p_k \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i \right)^{n-1} p_k \\
\end{split}
$$
where the second line follows by independence, and third line follows by the fact that the distributions are identical for each $n$.